# Using Update Cursor gives IndexError: list assignment index out of range?

Tags: arcpy, cursor, update, indexerror, boolean

I am trying to use an update cursor and receiving an error. I'm not very familiar with using cursors, so please bear with me. I am trying to write a 1 or 0 to a field, based on a condition. 
The error I am receiving is:

> IndexError: list assignment index out of range.

I have googled around and have seen solutions, but I'm still not understanding *why* its throwing an error.

```
#Define Environments
rasters = r"C:\Data.gdb"
points = r"C:\Data.gdb\Points"

#Set workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = rasters
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
# Get a list of the rasters in the workspace  
rasters = arcpy.ListRasters()
# Loop through the list of rasters  
for inRaster in rasters:  
    print str("Processing " + inRaster)
    rastername = str(inRaster)
    fieldname = str(inRaster + "_perf_flag")
    # Add surface information to Well FC
    arcpy.AddSurfaceInformation_3d(points,inRaster , "Z", "LINEAR")
    print "Formation Depth Added"
    # Create positive values from SS values
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(points, "Z", '!Z!*-1', "PYTHON")
    print "Depth Values Made Positive"
    # Add new field name for perf flag
    arcpy.AddField_management(points, fieldname, "LONG", 9, "", "", fieldname, "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED")
    print "Flag Field Added"
    # Raname Z field as formation grid name
    arcpy.AlterField_management(points, 'Z', rastername, rastername)
    print "Field Altered"
    # Calculate if well was perfed in the formation - Flag 1 as yes - Flag 0 as no
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(points, ["Base", "Top",rastername, fieldname]) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            if (row[3] >= row[0] and row[3] <= row[1]):
                row[4] = 1
            if not (row[3] >= row[0] and row[3] <= row[1]):
                row[4] = 0
                cursor.updateRow(row)
        print "Processing perf flags for " + rastername
```

Comment: Python Array Use 101: indexes start at zero, and you only provide four field names, so `row[4]` is out of range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your update cursor has four values in its row: `["Base", "Top",rastername, fieldname]` corresponding to `row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3]` respectively. `row[4]` is out of range because it is the fifth of four items.

Comment: Thanks for the help.I'm not sure how I missed that, as I accounted for row[0].. I adjusted the script and it ran as expected. Thanks again for looking it over!